# How can I call different WP page depending on some conditions?

Tags: php, wordpress

Let's say I have a page A and a page B that I created with the Wordpress dashboard. I have written a function in function.php that basically return 1 or 0 depending on whether the user succesfully logged in or not. How can I code that I want page A to be built if I got 1 or page B if I got 0 ?

Comment: Past the code, you have tried.

Comment: Actually I'm using a theme (Lydia), so the pages seems to be built with a file called page_visual_composer.php where you can find this :

<?php 
 session_start();
 get_header();
 the_post();
 the_content();
 get_footer();
?>

I'd like to know how to choose which "the_post" and "the_content" he is building.
(Btw I'm not very familiar yet with Wordpress, sorry if what I'm asking seems stupid)